# ASP.NET MVC Enterprise DDD Architecture and WCF layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, enterprise-architect

I've desgined my ASP.NET MVC application using the Domain Driven Design, and I got the following projects:

- MyApp.Core - the app core, contains the domain models etc.
- MyApp.Infrastructure - the app main infrastrucutre, contains implementation for the domain model storing (repos etc.) using EF.
- MyApp.Web.Core - domain models, services declaration (interfaces) and such only for web (e.g. IFormAuthenticationTicketSupplier, IOAuthAuthenticationProvider etc.)
- MyApp.Web.Infrastructure - web implementation
- MyApp.Web.UI - ASP.NET MVC standard application.

This application should be used by enterprise with multiple servers, etc. Currently, the application calls a service in the infrastructure layer at the controllers, which uses Repositories and EF. I can connect to the DB server using the connection string.

When digging about this topic at Google, I've read that some approches taken when creating an enterprise application are create an Application server and Web server. In the application server - storing a WCF service, and in the web server just calling it.

I'd like to know if I should do so (if creating a WCF service is the right and required approch when dealing with enterprises):
- Why should someone not just use the Services in the controllers and instead use an API?
- In case I'm using an API, it won't slow down the response? since even if the computers are on the same network, I still open an HTTP request.
- If I should use WCF, or ASP.NET WebAPI?

Thanks for any feedback and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, regarding your projects, is there a need to split up MyApp.Web.Core, MyApp.Web.Infrastructure and MyApp.Web.UI? Sure they may be separate responsibilities, but sometimes dependency hygiene trumps encapsulation. You can always leave them in separate folders and namespaces. I wouldn't extract something into a separate project unless I needed to reference that as a library from elsewhere.

As far as the application service, that also depends on your needs. If the only place that would call that application service is the ASP.NET MVC app, then there isn't much of a need to extract an application service. There are some benefits however. One is that you don't have to worry about all of the dependencies required for a service - you just references it via Url. And of course you have the ability to call the service from places other than the controller, although the MVC controller can act as a pure HTTP service as well. You also have the ability to deploy updates to a specific service without releasing the MVC app. But you do have the burden of maintaining a separate service. If you do go that route, go with the WebAPI, WCF is just too much abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. About the seperation - I had to mention it, I've done that because I wish to use this project in the future for Windows 8 app, WP, iOS (Mono), Android (Mono) etc. So I thought that this will be a good approch. Because of these applications - I do think that I'll need to use WebAPI or WCF in the future (In this case, that I'll develop apps for iOS, Android etc. you still recommend WCF?). Will the usage of WebAPI or WCF slow down the performance (when assuming that the service is on the same network)?

Comment: For HTTP services, I recommend WebAPI over WCF. WCF for HTTP is quite limited and unnatural compared to WebAPI. And a process hop will always slow down performance, but it shouldn't be a problem. You can actually have the HTML client call the WebAPI service directly for certain things.

Comment: Thanks - so I'll choose the WebAPI. Last sub-question: Would you think that it'll be OK to use the service both on the standard Web application controllers AND in the WebAPI? so the web application won't be slowed down because of the HTTP request, but all the other applications (iOS, Android, AJAX calls) will use the WebAPI?

Comment: You can do that yes, though then you have to take care of versioning. Also as I stated in the post, especially if the API is small, you can have MVC act as a WebAPI by returning JSON instead of HTML, for instance.